# How to use easy_install with python 3.3 while 2.7 is also installed

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, python-3.3, easy-install

I am using ubuntu with root access and have python 3.3 and 2.7 installed in my system. When I use easy_install by default it installs the package for 2.7.

How can I use it to install to 3.3 instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested on Ubuntu 14.04:

1) Use `pip` instead of `easy_install`. It's the way of the future. ;-)

2) `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

3) `sudo pip3 install AWESOME-PACKAGE`